# Using all UDP ports?

Tags: macos, udp

On a mac, I do:

```
lsof -i udp
```

I notice a few entries for Skype.

```
COMMAND     PID USER FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Skype       271 me   16u  IPv4 0xc1ff6619a243d125      0t0  UDP localhost:58148
Skype       271 me   19u  IPv4 0xc1ff6619a243d745      0t0  UDP *:*
```

the first entry I guess tells me Skype is using the 58148 port.  What is the second entry saying *.*?

It's using all ports on all machines. Hardly.

Any help appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UDP *:*` is an UDP socket, which is not bound and not connected. You could create it with something like this:

```
perl -MSocket -e 'socket(my $fh,AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,17) or die $!; sleep(1000)'
```